# Connecting to database with SQLAlchemy and confusion on formatting connection string

Tags: python, c#, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a program that reads csv files and pushes the data to a simple database written in C#.

I am trying to adapt a version of it to run in Python as part of another project, however, I've run into an issue trying to understand how to format the connection string.

Originally, the connection string for my local database that appears in C# is:

"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Reports_DB;Integrated Security=True"

I am trying to figure out how this can be rewritten to be a valid create_engine assignment:

```
import sqlalchemy as db

engine = db.create_engine('connection string goes here')
conn = engine.connect()
```

I've looked up various examples but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Make sure SQLAlchemy supports your database: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/index.html

Comment: It's microsoft sql 2017, so it should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy connection string depends on dialect and driver you want to use.

**For MS SQL Server**:

**pyodbc**: `mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<dsnname>`

**pymssql**: `mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<freetds_name>/?charset=utf8`

**aioodbc**: `mssql+aioodbc://<username>:<password>@<dsnname>`

**For other database dialects** you can find connection strings in the SQLAlchemy documentation. Start from this link, chose your database dialect and then choose driver you want to use: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/index.html

Comment: I'm assuming that pyodbc is the one I would use... but it's a local database. I'm not connecting to an external server.

I am looking at my settings in MS SQL Server Manager and they look something like this:

Server: LS-12345 (The computer name)
Connection: LS\USERNAME

It's just a local database running off of SQL Express.

I've also tried pymysql using this:

create_engine('mssql+pymysql://LS\USERNAME@localhost/Reports_DB')


but it keeps saying: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mssql.pymysql